# How to add native custom views to HTML pages in PhoneGap/Cordova?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, android-custom-view, cordova-3

I am developing an Android PhoneGap application, where I need to add my custom camera/gallery views to HTML page - for example some empty DIV in my HTML Page, whose ID, I already have. How to achieve it?

I know how to write Plugins and basic HTML stuff.

is there any way, I can access elements of current HTML page in Cordova Webview?

my requirement is to add my customized camera view to HTML page with whatever dimensions I can.

Comment: Do u want to achieve the gallery which contains the images from the phone in cordova?

Comment: Not Specifically gallery but any custom view developed in native (Android in my case) has to be attached/appeared in HTML.

Answer (score 6):

Update the answer:

I finally figured out how to do this.

First of all, you need to add your view, such as button, into the Cordova WebView.
The Cordova WebView takes care the scroll.

```
webview.addView(button);
```

https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/blob/master/src/android/plugin/google/maps/GoogleMaps.java#L373

If the device orientation is changed, you need to change the size.
But in Cordova, you can't not receive the event in java, so you need to listen the event in JavaScript.

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", onMapResize);
```

https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/blob/master/www/googlemaps-cdv-plugin.js#L1381

And here is the key point.
Change the position in HTML to the point in View,
you can do this

```
Math.round(d * webView.getScale());
```

https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/blob/master/src/android/plugin/google/maps/GoogleMaps.java#L383

Here is my plugin. I embed a Google Maps Android API v2 into the specified div tag.

[image]

Comment: interesting post, if understand it correctly you have injected java elements into the page? so you can control the page via js but this elements is being rendering via native code?

Comment: Yes. WebView is java element, so you can add your child element (such as button) on the browser view.
Currently, I changed this method.
Put java element under the webview.
https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Map#how-does-the-plugin-work

Comment: nice stuff! is it possible to do it over a camera screen as well?

Comment: Yes, I tested that privately previously.

Comment: do you mind to share the code for this kind of test? do you know if its the same case for ios as well?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not share the code. The code is for private work. And the same idea works on iOS as well.